# If exists update else create. Either case return the record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Given `guid` and `value`. If a record exists with that `guid`, update its `value`. Otherwise, create a new record with that `guid` and `value`. Either case, return the record so that I can get its primary key `id`.

How to do this with:

- as less database queries as possible
- as less code as possible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest thing is probably

```
object = Model.find_or_initialize_by_guid(guid)
object.update_attributes :value => value
```

Which always does 2 queries (a find and an insert/update)

If you know ahead of time that collisions are unlikely you could do

```
begin
  Model.create(:guid => guid, :value => value)
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique
  # find and update existing record
end
```

This requires a unique index on the guid column. It requires 3 queries in the update case but only 1 query in the create case.

This all assumes we are talking SQL - other datastores, such as mongodb, have the concept of an upsert (update or insert) operation

Answer (score 1):

This code will find an object which value = params[:guid]. If the object is found, it will return that object, otherwise it will instantiate a new object, but not yet save.

```
your_object = YOU_MODEL.find_or_initialize_by(params[:guid])
```

Comment: `guid` is a field, not a model

Comment: Could you give your model and your params object?

Comment: find_or_initialize_by() does not update the record if it exists in DB already. Note that `value` may be different from what it is in DB.